# Retrieve all user all recent tweets from past 7 days and then retrieve all users who replied to those tweets

Tags: python, twitter

What I want to do is to learn which is better way to get all tweets from a user profile URL and then get all users who replied to those tweets and remove duplicates from list before adding them in to csv or excel file. I found this Git project but its not what I want

https://github.com/nirholas/Get-Tweet-Replies-With-Python-Tweepy

Could anyone guide me to a better library or idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy is a very good library for interacting with Twitter in Python.

I'd suggest taking a look at Tweepy's [documentation and starter guide](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html). It's quite simple to work with once you understand what functions are available.